# How to not need to substitute ICollection to ObservableCollection in TT-file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, collections, observablecollection, data-modeling

Every time I create a new data model with EF, I have to enter the TT file and substitute each occurrence of *ICollection* and the first occurrence of *HashSet* for *ObservableCollection* as well as the namespace *Generic* for *ObjectModel*.

The process is described [on the internet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574514.aspx) (the bullet list right above "*Lazy Loading*" section) and seems to be as a hacky work-around for a shortcoming of a new technology, which with time should have been remedied and not needed.

Is it possible to automatically create observable collection or is the approach described the most efficient and generally applied?

Comment: I've had to edit TT files on multiple occasions and even though it may *seem* hacky, I've found it to be a very efficient and surprisingly solid approach to custom generation. So IMHO, edit the TT file (you only need to do it once)

Comment: @NielsFilter: Once in _every_ project. That's the problem, especially in an enterprise, where dozens of developers creating (in side project's or in utilities) data models with EF. DRY.

Comment: Don't repeat yourself. Sorry for the missing link in the _comment_, there is a link in my answer. And also sorry for the ambiguity, that comment was adressed to Niels (now edited), not to your original question.

Comment: @g.pickardou (Hint: I'm pulling your leg, here.)

Comment: There is some mix in the title on your model class's interface (a navigation property type: ICollection), and its internal implementation (ObservableCollection). Note: The property still can declared ICollection because both HashSet both ObservableCollection implement ICollection. You are asking about how to change the implementation. Btw as I see lazy loading (as a concept) has nothing to do with this implementation change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think customizing a .TT template for your need is an acceptable (or more: best) practice. The only question, Do this customizing process repeatedly/manually *or* create your own .TT and install it as [Visual Studio Item Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx). My vote goes to this second option, which is a little application of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

However you need to prepare yourself to a drawback: When original .TT item templates will change (new version, etc) then you should apply those changes on your custom templates too. The easiest way to do this: diff, then choose the most efficient way: Replicate version changes on your custom template *or* reapply your customization changes on the new version.

Comment: Good to know I'm not totally off. +1 for the informative linkage.